# onclick event in select HTML not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events

I have an ASP.NET dropdown list control with `onclick` and `onchange` JavaScript events.
Both work in IE, Mozilla, Opera and Chrome, but not in Safari. When I remove the `onclick` event, `onchange` suddenly works.

The reason I use `onclick` is to get the value of the dropdown list before it changes. Is there a way I can do that without using `onclick`? That is, get the value of the dropdown list before it changes/a new value is selected? I want to do this in JavaScript only.

Comment: i've replaced the onclick event to onfocus. problem solved. i guess safari dont like onclick event on select element

Comment: Sorry to bump. For me, I found out that I was using `closest` which was not supported and that fixes it, after debugging with `alert` (no `console.log` on mobile ;))..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing the `onclick` event with `onfocus` solved the problem. I guess Safari doesn't like `onclick` event on `select` elements.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you need to add preference to the JavaScript function as "javascript:"; for example:

```
<select onclick="changeDate()">
```

should be

```
<select onclick="javascript:changeDate()">
```

Comment: What helped me was making sure `javascript:` and `()` were both there.

Comment: @redolent so you weren't sure and it didn't work, than you looked, made sure and it started working? :-D

Comment: It was that simple, yes

Comment: wow... this helped me 10 years later.... I don't understand why safari has to be build different like this...

Answer (score 1):

For me in Chrome, onclick working with second click on select box Where as in FF & IE, its working fine for first click itself.

Comment: This really isn't a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

`<select onclick="changeDate()">`

Should be changed to

```
<select onchange="changeDate()">
```

Safari seems to react as a open even and not a close event, like in the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also be resolved by using the below code snippet:

`<select onmousedown="if(event.button==0) changeDate()">`