# OnClick not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have a button that submits a form. When someone clicks it I want to disable it and I want a little loading icon to appear inside of it. The following code works in all browsers but Safari.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_button" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('loadinggif').style='height:20px;';
        document.getElementById('thetext').style='display:none';
        document.getElementById('submit_button').className='btn btn-primary some-class disabled';">
        <div id="thetext">Submit Form</div><img id="loadinggif" class="img-responsive center-block" src="/img/loading.gif" style="display:none;height:20px;"></button>
```

In Safari, the above code causes the button to 'freeze' as the form is submitting and does not execute any of the javascript.

I have tried all possible combinations: I moved the javascript into a function, I added and removed the `javascript:` prefix and appended `return true;` or `return false;` to the end of the javascript (inline or in a function), I even tried to submit the form from within the javascript itself. Nothing worked (on Safari).

UPDATE

If I remove the form submit, the button css changes work. For some reason style changes in combination with submitting a form does not work on Safari. I also tried it with JQuery and same issue.

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769374/onclick-event-in-select-html-not-working-in-safari)?

Comment: Is your closing `</button>` tag really at the very end?

Comment: @Kevin Yes. Did not fix the issue.

Comment: @RaxWeber Yes, I double checked.

Comment: If you click what is safari doing nothing? or only not showing loading icon? You can check this by adding a alert inside you're javascript.

Comment: I did some research and it looks like that safari has some trouble with .getElementById so you can try to use JQeury something like this: $("#id").click

Comment: @N.Smeding No luck with JQuery. Same issue.