# inline onclick event in Safari not working

Tags: javascript, html, safari

First I did some research and I found these 2 relevant questions :

1. [onclick event in select HTML not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769374/onclick-event-in-select-html-not-working-in-safari)
2. [OnClick not working on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279820/onclick-not-working-on-safari?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Now I have tried both solutions, each one of them and everything works in Chrome/Firefox but for safari its just not working.

**Problem:**

I have an `li` with an `a` tag which has a inline `onclick` event that loads more products but for some reason on Safari if i click on the `a` tag nothing happens, how is this possible?

**Code:**

```
<li id="page_size_8">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return marketplaceLogin.setPageSize(\'page_size\', '.$maxAmount.', \'All\');">
        All
    </a>
</li>
```

Just to make it clear this is **what ive tried** and it not working:

```
<li id="page_size_8">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onfocus="return marketplaceLogin.setPageSize(\'page_size\', '.$maxAmount.', \'All\');">
        All
    </a>
</li>

<li id="page_size_8">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:return marketplaceLogin.setPageSize(\'page_size\', '.$maxAmount.', \'All\');">
        All
    </a>
</li>
```

**JS for PageSize:**

```
setPageSize: function (fieldId, fieldValue, fieldLabel) {
    "use strict";
    if (typeof fieldId !== "undefined" && typeof fieldValue !== "undefined" && typeof fieldLabel !== "undefined") {
        if (fieldValue !== null && fieldValue !== "" && fieldId !== null && fieldId !== "" && fieldLabel !== null && fieldLabel !== "") {
            if (!isNaN(fieldValue)) {
                fieldValue = parseInt(fieldValue, 10);
                if (fieldValue < 5) {
                    fieldValue = 5;
                }

                var selectId = '#filter_select_marketplace_login_' + fieldId;

                // Update the hidden field
                $('input[name=page_size').val(fieldValue);

                // Update the dropdown
                //window.filterSlider.updateSelectedLabel(selectId);
                $(selectId + ' .dropdown_selected_label_left').html(fieldLabel);

                // Load page 1, this closes the dropdown instantly
                if (typeof window.page_name !== "undefined") {
                    switch (window.page_name) {
                        case 'marketplaceloginproducts':
                            marketplaceLogin.loadProductPage(1);
                            break;
                        case 'marketplaceloginorders':
                            marketplaceLogin.loadOrderPage(1);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: is marketplaceLogin a global variable?

Comment: yess its an object in the js file

Comment: Do you get any errors on console?

Comment: @Huangism thanks for response, no errors in the console, not on load, not on click

Comment: Can you post the code for the declaration of `marketplaceLogin` and the actual setPageSize function please

Comment: @Huangism are you sure i meen then why would it work in chrome and Firefox?

Comment: I am sure about you posting more code but not sure why it is not working because I haven't seen your code. If you could simplify your code and put it on here via a snippet or https://jsfiddle.net then it would be much easier to help you

Comment: @Huangism this is something thats been build into a CMS using controllers and classes i cant duplicate the functionality in a jsfiddle, it wont work, and i cant think that it has anything to do with the decleration becuase then it would not have worked on chrome or firefox, i appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: You need to add more code for people to help you. With your current markup how can anyone figure out what went wrong? I made this https://jsfiddle.net/45zpw88y/2/ and it works in Safari. Just post simplified code, it doesn't need to replicate the exact functionality but just a test to see if the function is called

Comment: i see your fiddle and it works even in my safari let me test an alert on my `onclick` if that does work i know its my function, which is weird becuase it works in other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be calling the function directly without return

```
<li id="page_size_8">
   <a onclick="marketplaceLogin.setPageSize()">All</a>
</li>
```

> missing ] closing brace on input selection

```
$(input[name=page_size]).val(fieldsvalue)
```

Tested it in safari and it worked if that doesn't work I'd suspect it may be another issue.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxebxR?editors=1111

Comment: this is still inline ?

Comment: but does it work? I've tested it in safari and it logged to the console as expected

Comment: if it still doesn't work can you post your javascript :)

Comment: let me also try without return

Comment: after testing it with "javascript:return"  and without it does resolve the issue at least for me without.

Comment: @JoeWarner like you mentioned could be js throwing the error and after removing return i found a console error (`$(input[name=page_size).val(fieldsvalue)`) so ill be closing that tag and then lets see man

Comment: if you look at my code pen looks like the issue was the /' when passing params into the function because you're using double " you can use single ' inside without having to escape them :) hope i've helped

Comment: it was as mentioned above, the closing bracket bro , but thanks you helped allot man appreciate

Comment: yeah been abit weird gone down to -2 then up to +1 as long as i've help :) have a nice day bro.

Comment: please update and add the bracket so i can accept, thanks allot

Answer (score -2):

I suspect that the issue is that the `javascript` namespace is being used for both the `href` and the `onclick`.

Try:

1. Replacing with `href="#"`
2. Dropping the href

You could also move the logic from the `onclick` to the `href` - although I would advise against this, as it's not best practice.

Comment: hi, thanks, but replacing with `href="#"` makes the page jump that is why i use `javascript:void(0);`, aslo dropping the `href` is not preferred as you know yourself, and even if i test it its not working

Comment: This isn't how onclick and href interact at all.  Try `<a onclick="alert('one')" href="javascript:alert('two')">test</a>` as demonstration

Comment: @DanielBeck I stand corrected - thanks for the example!